# Create a pdf on the go and send via swiftmailer

Tags: php, drupal, tcpdf, swiftmailer

I am trying to create a PDF with TCPDF and send it via SwiftMailer, since Drupal Mail does not allow attachments.This is my current code:

```
public function getPdfReport($document){
    $html = '<head>'.document["body"].'</head>'.'<body>'.document["head"].'</body>';
    $tcpdf = tcpdf_get_instance();
    $tcpdf->DrupalInitialize(array(
  'footer' => array(
    'html' => 'This is a test!! <em>Bottom of the page</em>',
  ),
  'header' => array(
    'callback' => array(
      'function' => 'tcpdf_example_default_header',
      'context' => array(
        'welcome_message' => 'Hello, tcpdf example!',
      ),
    ),
  ),
));
$tcpdf->writeHTML($document);

    return  $pdf->Output('', 'S');
}
public function sendReportEmail($name,$to, $langcode,$attachment){
    $mailManager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail');
    $send = true;
    $module = 'order';
    $key = 'updated_password';

    $result = $mailManager->mail($module, $key, $to, $langcode, $this->getEmail($langcode, $name, $attachment), NULL, true);
}
private function getEmail($lang, $name,$attachment){
    $message = null;
    $pdfFile = new stdClass();
    $pdfFile->uri = $this->getPdfReport($attachment);
    $pdfFile->filename = 'EVG_invoice.pdf';
    $pdfFile->filemime = 'application/pdf';
    $message["files"] = $pdfFile;
    if($lang=="en"){
        $message["message"] = "
Dear ".$name.",

You successfully completed your online order.
Attached you can find a summary of your order.
Please print attached file and send it with your samples.";

$message["title"] = "order summary";}
return $message;
}
```

Am I missing something here? SwiftMailer is set as default in Drupal. The keys and module are fine as well.

Comment: What errors do you see? Does it work? SO is not code-review tool. It is [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Jakujei don't see any errors, it doesn't work, there are no files getting attached. All I see is a 500 internal server error since the function is getting called via ajax.

Comment: Then you will see the error and what is wrong in the server log.

Comment: The problem is I don't see any errors. I can't even debug. The function just doesn't finish...

Comment: If you see error 500, it finishes and, there should be some error logged in HTTP server. If it is not, then you should configure it.